# Problem updating parent state from child component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a class component(actually the collection of the same components) where I have 2 buttons + and - to increase and decrease quantity of watches. Min amount of watches is 1 and max amount is 10. I have regulated this with this 2 functions increaseAmountHandler and decreaseAmountHandler. With this two buttons it's all ok. But the problem is that I have to sum up the value of calculated watches in parent component and I cannot forward the summed up values of the watches to a parent component to state variable totalAmount. Cannot use Redux becacuse it's a collection of watches component and each have own + and - button already occupied with this 2 increaseAmountHandler, decreaseAmountHandler functions.
Anyone idea how to solve this?

Child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Modal from '.././UI/Modal';

class SelectedWatch extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            watchQuantity: 1,
            watchAmount: 1
        }
    }

    increaseAmountHandler = () => {
        if(this.state.watchQuantity < 1) {
            this.setState({
                watchQuantity: 0, 
                watchAmount: 0
            })
            return;
        } else if (this.state.watchQuantity >= 10){
            this.setState({
                watchQuantity: 10,
                watchAmount: this.props.selectedWatch.selectedWatchPrice * this.state.watchQuantity
            })
            return;
        }

        this.setState({
            watchQuantity: this.state.watchQuantity + 1,
            watchAmount: this.props.selectedWatch.selectedWatchPrice * this.state.watchQuantity
        })
    }

    decreaseAmountHandler = () => {
        if(this.state.watchQuantity < 1) {
            this.setState({
                watchQuantity: 0,
                watchAmount: 0
            })
            return;
        } else if (this.state.watchQuantity >= 10){
            this.setState({
                watchQuantity: 9,
                watchAmount: this.props.selectedWatch.selectedWatchPrice * this.state.watchQuantity
            })
            return;
        }

        this.setState({
            watchQuantity: this.state.watchQuantity - 1,
            watchAmount: this.props.selectedWatch.selectedWatchPrice * this.state.watchQuantity
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className={"shopping-cart-product" + (this.state.watchQuantity < 1 ? ' notDisplayed' : '')}>
                <div className="product-info">
                    <div>
                        <h3>{this.props.selectedWatch.selectedWatchName}</h3>
                        <p>${this.props.selectedWatch.selectedWatchPrice} &times; {this.state.watchQuantity}</p>
                    </div>
                    <img src={this.props.selectedWatch.selectedWatchUrl} />
                </div>
                <div className="product-count">
                    <button onClick={this.decreaseAmountHandler}>-</button>
                    <span>{this.state.watchQuantity}</span>
                    <button onClick={this.increaseAmountHandler}>+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default SelectedWatch;
```

Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import EnteredWatch from '.././components/EnteredWatch/EnteredWatch';
import SelectedWatch from '.././components/SelectedWatch/SelectedWatch';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            watchName: '',
            watchDescription: '',
            watchUrl: '',
            watchPrice: '',
            watchId: '',
            watchAmount: '',
            watchQuantity: 1, 
            enteredWatchList: [],
            selectedWatchName: '',
            selectedWatchDescription: '',
            selectedWatchUrl: '',
            selectedWatchPrice: '',
            selectedWatchId: '',
            selectedWatchAmount: '', 
            selectedWatchQuantity: 1, 
            selectedWatchList: [],
            totalAmount: 0,
        }
    }

        submitHandler = (event) => {

            event.preventDefault();

            let watchId = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
            let watchName = this.state.watchName;
            let watchDescription = this.state.watchDescription;
            let watchUrl = this.state.watchUrl;
            let watchPrice = this.state.watchPrice;
            let watchQuantity = this.state.watchQuantity;

            this.setState({
                enteredWatchList: this.state.enteredWatchList.concat({watchName, watchUrl, watchDescription, watchPrice, watchId, watchQuantity})
            })

        add = (selectedWatchName, selectedWatchUrl, selectedWatchDescription, selectedWatchPrice, index, selectedWatchQuantity) => {

            let arr = this.state.selectedWatchList;

            let found = arr.some(el => {
                return el.selectedWatchName === selectedWatchName;
            });

            if (!found) { 
                return arr.concat({selectedWatchName, selectedWatchUrl, selectedWatchDescription, selectedWatchPrice, index, selectedWatchQuantity});
            } else {
                return this.state.selectedWatchList;
            }

        }

        buyWatchHandler = (selectedWatchName, selectedWatchUrl, selectedWatchDescription, selectedWatchPrice, index, selectedWatchQuantity) => {

            let arr = this.add(selectedWatchName, selectedWatchUrl, selectedWatchDescription, selectedWatchPrice, index, selectedWatchQuantity);

            this.setState({
                selectedWatchName: selectedWatchName,
                selectedWatchUrl: selectedWatchUrl,
                selectedWatchDescription: selectedWatchDescription,
                selectedWatchPrice: selectedWatchPrice,
                selectedWatchId: index,
                selectedWatchQuantity: selectedWatchQuantity, 
                selectedWatchList: arr
            });
        }

        render() {

            const enteredWatches = this.state.enteredWatchList.map((enteredWatch, index) => {
                return <EnteredWatch
                    key={index}
                    enteredWatch={enteredWatch}
                    selected={this.buyWatchHandler.bind(this, enteredWatch.watchName, enteredWatch.watchUrl,
                        enteredWatch.watchDescription, enteredWatch.watchPrice, index, enteredWatch.watchQuantity)}
                />
            });

            const selectedWatches = this.state.selectedWatchList.map((selectedWatch, index) => {
                const active = this.state.activeIndex;
                return <SelectedWatch
                    key={index}
                    active={index === active}
                    selectedWatch={selectedWatch}
                />
            });

            return (
                <div className="App">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="container">
                            <div className="add-product">
                               <form>
                                    <div>
                                        <label>Product name:</label>
                                        <input 
                                            type="text" 
                                            placeholder="Casio Watch" 
                                            required
                                            value={this.state.watchName}
                                            onChange={event => this.setState({watchName: event.target.value})}
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <label>Product description:</label>
                                        <textarea 
                                            placeholder="Sample description..."
                                            value={this.state.watchDescription}
                                            onChange={event => this.setState({watchDescription: event.target.value})}
                                        >
                                        </textarea>
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <label>Product image:</label>
                                        <input 
                                            type="text" 
                                            placeholder="http://...jpg"
                                            value={this.state.watchUrl}
                                            pattern="https?://.+" required
                                            onChange={event => this.setState({watchUrl: event.target.value})}
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <label>Product price:</label>
                                        <input 
                                            type="number" 
                                            min="0" 
                                            placeholder="22" 
                                            value={this.state.watchPrice}
                                            onChange={event => this.setState({watchPrice: event.target.value})}
                                        />
                                    </div>

                                    <button
                                        type="submit"
                                        onClick={event => this.submitHandler(event)}
                                    >
                                        Add a new Task
                                    </button>
                                </form>
                             </div>

                             <div className="list-products">
                                <ul>
                                   {enteredWatches}
                                </ul> 
                            </div>

                            <div className="shopping-cart">
                                <div className="shopping-cart-products">
                                    <ul>
                                       {selectedWatches}
                                    </ul> 

                                </div>
                                <div className="shopping-cart-summary">
                                    <div>Total: <b>${this.state.totalAmount}</b></div>
                                    <div><button onClick={this.summaryHandler}>Purchase</button></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent has to keep track of how many watches have been added.

Make the parent smart (has state), and the children dumb (no state).
Manage all the state in the parent, and put the click handlers in the parent too.

Pass those handlers down to the child, to be fired when its buttons are clicked.  Something like this:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  this.state = {
    cart: [],
    watches: [
      { id: 1, name: "Casio", description: "...", price: 25 },
      { id: 2, name: "Rolex", description: "...", price: 3000 },
      { id: 3, name: "Timex", description: "...", price: 10 },
    ],
  }

  handleClickIncrement = (watchId) => {
    //add it to the cart (or increment it if its already there)
  }

  handleClickDecrement = (watchId) => {
    //remove it from the cart (or deccrement it if its already there)
  }

  getCartTotal() {
    //loop over cart and calculate
  }

  renderWatches() {
    this.state.watches.map(watch => (
      <Watch id={watch.id}
        name={watch.name}
        description={watch.description}
        price={watch.price}
        onClickIncrement={() => { this.handleClickIncrement(watch.id); }} 
        onClickDecrement={() => { this.handleClickDecrement(watch.id); }} 
    ))
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <h1>Our selection of watches:</h1>
      {this.renderWatches()}

      <h1>Your cart total: {this.getCartTotal()}</h1>
    </div>
  }
}


class Watch extends React.Component {
  props = {
    id,
    name,
    description,
    price,
    quantityInCart,
    onClickIncrementButton,
    onClickDecrementButton
  }

  render() {
    <div>
      <h1>{this.props.name}</h1>
      <p>{this.props.description}</p>
      <h5>${this.props.price}</h5>
      <button onClick={this.props.onClickIncrementButton}>+</button>
      <button onClick={this.props.onClickDecrementButton}>-</button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Alan P. I can not create data on my own, they are brought from form fileds

Comment: Ok that's fine, so initially in my example `this.state.watches` would be an empty array, and objects get added to it when the form is submitted.

Comment: The point stays the same: keep the state in the parent, make the children stateless, and pass down functions to the child that will change the parent's state.

Comment: Alan P. You are definitely right, it can be controlled only from parent component in this case. I did a lot of modifications, and now it's working. Thanks for your help.